# Performing crontab-like numeric matching in a shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, cron

What would be the most straightforward way to emulate the same numeric matching that is used for the expressions in the first five fields of a crontab line?

For example, given inputs of a pattern "1,5-7,16,*/3" (silly example, I know) and a value "6", the output would be a boolean true.

If there isn't a dead simple solution, it'd be realistic in my situation to provide a third input which would specify the maximum value that an asterisk would need to match, so that asterisks (along with the hyphenated ranges) could be translated to a list of values and the input value could be matched against that list.  (The list of the example pattern above would be "1,3,5,6,7,9,12,15,16,18", given a maximum value of "18".)

Thanks!

Comment: What all have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm mostly a ksh person, but my experience with bash says this should work (given your example), or at least point you towards what needs to be done.

```
hrVal=6
case ${hrVal} in   
   1|[5-7]|16 ) print -- "true" ;;
   * ) print -- "false" ;;
esac
```

**Edit 2018-08-20** For `bash`, you'll need to change `print --` to either `echo ....` or `printf "%s\n"`.

In reality, I would remove the `print -- ""` stuff, and just call `exit 0` or `exit 1`, which will then exit with the appropriate return code, that can then be tested by the calling process.

---

to include the rest of your example, I had to do

```
  hrVal=6
  eval "
    case ${hrVal} in

      1|[5-7]|16|$(( ${hrVal} / 3 )) ) print -- "true" ;;
      * ) print -- "false" ;;
    esac
 "
```

So, this could be exciting!

- Parse each of 5 time bands as above
- apply sed like commands to convert he entries like 1,5-7,16 into 1|[5-7]|16
- trap and convert your math expressions into evaluatable  expressions 
       (oh, you can probably get the result before the case statement and
         just merge the value into the ....) save all derived values as
  variables,
- use those variables as case targets, possible wrapping the whole thing and escaping chars as needed with an eval.
- evaluate the combined truth of all 5 columns return values (any false == false)

(maybe it is (( ${hrVal} / 3 ))  in bash )

IHTH

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful; the (( ${hrVal} / 3 )) matching didn't seem to be working for me, so I ended up writing a function to specifically handle the those patterns.

I'm a bit new to shell scripts, so there may be an easier way to do this, but here's the script that I ended up using:
http://pastie.org/1758972

Comment: @Tom : (How did you join so late and still get a 3 letter name!? ;-) (no need to reply on that) )... Very nice. Excellent comments. The major thing I would consider changing is your use of a file divisors.txt and reading it from a file. Use your ${divisors} variable and just use `print -- "${divisors}" | while read divisors ...  ; done`. Also, backticks are deprecated, used $( ) and never have to worry about figuring out how to nest command substitutions in the future. ;-)  All in all, very good for someone 'new to shell scripts.' You have obviously done coding in other languages. Good luck!